# Meteor JS: Latency compensation with S3 image uploads?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, meteor

I'm a Meteor beginner and trying to figure out how to implement latency compensation when uploading images to S3.

I would like to show a blob of the image, while the image is uploading to Amazon S3 in the background. When the S3 upload is complete, the img src should change to the S3 URL seamlessly. Unfortunately, I have not been successful.

I've tried creating a stub method, but instead of the images swapping out seamless, I see a white flash, then the blob, then a white flash again for a few seconds, and then the final S3 image.

Here is my code:

```
Images = new Meteor.Collection('images');

Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/'
  });
  this.route('image', {
    path: '/:_id',
    data: function() {
      return Images.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
  });
});


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.home.events({
    'dragover .dropzone' : function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(e.currentTarget).addClass('dragover');
    },

    'drop .dropzone' : function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var imageId = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()._str;
      var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
      var blob = URL.createObjectURL(file);

      Router.go('image', {_id: imageId});

      // Create file reader.
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function() {

        var img = {
          _id: imageId,
          binary: this.result,
          blob: blob,
          fileType: file.type
        };

        Meteor.call('uploadImage', img, function(error, url) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log(url);
          }
        });
      }

      // Read file,
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
  });

  Meteor.methods({
    uploadImage: function(image) {
      var imageId = image._id;
      var blob = image.blob
      Images.upsert( image._id, { $set: {image_src: blob} } );
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    uploadImage: function(image) {
      var imageId = image._id;
      var filename = "foobar2" + ".png";

      AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
        secretAccessKey: 'SECRET'
      });

      s3 = new AWS.S3();
      var buffer = new Buffer(image.binary, 'binary');
      var params = {
        Bucket: "proof-dev",
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Key: filename,
        ContentType: image.fileType,
        Body: buffer
      };

      var insertImage = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
        Images.upsert( image._id, { $set: {image_src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/foobar/" + filename} } );
      }, function (e) {
        console.log(e);
      });

      s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          insertImage();
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I am using iron-router as well as Meteor `template-engine-preview-10.1`.